# Custom permalinks for single page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

What I'm trying to achieve is having a single Wordpress page that would "manage" multiple child paths:

```
/blog_url/user/john
```

and

```
/blog_url/user/steve
```

both paths call the same page `/about?name=`john or steve.

Is this possible in Wordpress or does it need a custom ReWriteRule?
If neither, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need a custom rewriterule in your htaccess to do that. Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/ /user/?name=$1 [NC]
```

And then you would use $_GET['name'] and use it in your page's code

Comment: I can't manage to make it work.

My url path is something like `http://domain.com/web/user/steve`

Even removing Wordpress rules and adding a script to the folder `/web/user/index.php`, I still get a 404.

This is what I'm trying.
`RewriteRule ^web/user/([^/]+)$ /web/user/?o=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Never mind, I was editing the wrong file.
It worked, but changing the destination path to a Wordpress page, the GET attributes (uid) don't get to the Post page.
`RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ /web/index.php?p=**pageID**&uid=$1 [NC,L]`
@barakadam

Comment: Got it working by ditching the .htaccess rules and using the Wordpress [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). It was easier than it looked.